# Android Ionic video switch to fullscreen flicker

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic on android devices, and there is a  tag in the HTML page. When I pushed the fullscreen button to make the video presented in fullscreen mode, there is a obvious flicker in the area of the  tag on the device.

During the flicker, I can see the wallpaper of the android phone and the icons of the apps on this device. Is this some issue with the native functions? And I also notice that when the keyboard hide/show a similar problem.

As you can see in the picture, when I am switching to the fullscreen, there is clearly a play button of the native player, after a second or so, the video will be playing.

[image]

here are some codes.

```
<div ng-click="play()" ng-show="showPlay" class="tutorial-play-button"><img src="images/welcomeNote/play.png"></img></div>
 <video id='video-widget' autoplay='true' autobuffer controls playsinline poster="null" style="width:100%;">
        <source src="{{src}}">
    </video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause is the Theme I use. I used a transparent theme in my app. I changed the theme to Theme.Light. It is OK.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not because of your mentioned code in the post. It might be because you have not handled your out activity action/animation correctly. Same thing will happen even when you launch another activity. There might be snippet of code in your project that is altering default behaviour of activity. You should google Activity Transition and you might have your solution.

I hope this helps.

Comment: The cause is the Theme I use. I used a transparent theme in my app. Thank you for answering